# assetlinks domain vs host

Tags: android, flutter, applinks

I am trying to setup applinks in my android app. In my manifest file I have something like this:

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="myapp.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

So my question is where EXACTLY will the app try to download the `assetlinks.json` file:

- a - `https://myapp.example.com/.well-know/assetlinks.json`
- b - `https://example.com/.well-know/assetlinks.json`
- c - `https://www.example.com/.well-know/assetlinks.json`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations?hl=en), it'll try to download from:

`https://myapp.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

Comment: yep, this makes sense. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: also, if I use a wildcard, like `android:host="*.example.com"`, do you think it goes to `https://example.com/.well-know/assetlinks.json` ?

Comment: I guess I found the answer to my 2nd question in the same link ;-) For those interested, if you use a wildcard, it will try to download from `https://example.com/.well-know/assetlinks.json`